# Should I use POST and DELETE or PATCH when designing REST API endpoints?

Tags: rest, api-design

I want to design a REST API two resources, **users** and **groups**. A user can join multiple groups and a group can have multiple users.

Let's assume you can access related resources via `/users/:id/groups` and `/groups/:id/users`. How would you design the enpoints for joining/leaving a group? I could do

`POST /users/:id/groups/:id` and `DELETE /users/:id/groups/:id`

but I could also go for

`PATCH /users/:id/groups/:id` and send a boolean.

Of course I don't need those endpoints for groups because they are redundant, this should be obvious. I'm not sure if this is a opinion based question, but what is the common way to deal with such relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach seems to be fine:

```
POST /users/:id/groups/:id
DELETE /users/:id/groups/:id
```

The [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) payload is not supposed to be a boolean value. The [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) payload is supposed to contain a set of instructions describing how the resource will be modified. Suitable formats are [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396). Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278775/1426227) for details.